# rspec controller post action test fails with ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError

Tags: ruby, rspec, controller, factory-bot

I want to test the post action of my controller but it fails with an `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError`.

require 'spec_helper'

```
describe HomeController do
  describe "POST #create" do
    context "with valid attributes" do
      it "saves the new feed in the database" do
        expect{
          post :create, feed: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:valid_feed)
        }.to change(Feed,:count).by(1)
      end
    end
end
```

Factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :valid_feed, class: Feed do
    title "CRE"
    address "http://cre.fm/feed/m4a/"
  end
  factory :invalid_feed, parent: :valid_feed do |f|
    f.address nil
  end
end
```

Controller:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
  def create
    @feed = Feed.new(params[:feed])
    if @feed.save
      redirect "/"
     else
      render nothing: true
    end
  end
end
```

I checked the params in controller to see if there is something wrong but params[:feed] contains a valid hash. 
Did I miss something here?

Comment: Is this Rails 3 or Rails 4?  If Rails 4, check out in the information on *strong parameters*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yup, you missed something.  Rails 4 has enabled [strong parameters](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters) by default.  You'll need to change it to something like this:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController

  def index
  end

  def create
    @feed = Feed.new(feed_params)
    if @feed.save
      redirect "/"
     else
      render nothing: true
    end
  end

  private

  def feed_params
    params.require(:feed).permit(:allowed, :elements, :of, :feed)
  end

end
```